# The update on the address field isn't working

Tags: django, updateview

I'm working on a Python/Django project. In the update view, I'm encountering a very specific issue:

When I try to update the bank_account field, the system updates it without any problems.
However, when I attempt to update the address field, the address doesn't get updated.
Here's the code:

```
class DeveloperUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Developer
    form_class = DeveloperForm
    template_name = 'developer/developer_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('backoffice:developer-list')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        object = Developer.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk'])
        developer_form = DeveloperForm(
            data=request.POST, instance=object, prefix='developer'
        )
        bank_account_form = developer_bank_account_formset(data=request.POST)
        address_form = developer_address_formset(data=request.POST)
        if developer_form.is_valid():
            developer = developer_form.save()
            if (
                bank_account_form.has_changed()
                and bank_account_form.is_valid()
            ):
                existing_bank_accounts = DeveloperBankAccount.objects.filter(
                    developer=developer
                )
                if existing_bank_accounts.exists():
                    existing_bank_accounts = existing_bank_accounts.first()

                    existing_bank_accounts.delete()
                bank_accounts = bank_account_form.save(commit=False)
                for bank_account in bank_accounts:
                    bank_account.developer = developer
                    bank_account.save()
            if (
                address_form.has_changed()
                 and address_form.is_valid()
            ):
                existing_addresses = DeveloperAddress.objects.filter(
                    developer=developer
                )
                if existing_addresses.exists():
                    existing_addresses = existing_addresses.first()

                    existing_addresses.delete()
                addresses = address_form.save(commit=False)
                for address in addresses:
                    address.developer = developer
                    address.save()

        else:
            return render(
                request,
                "developer/developer_form.html",
                {
                    "form": developer_form,
                    "bank_account_form": bank_account_form,
                    "address_form": address_form,
                    "action": "update",
                    "error": True,
                },
            )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('backoffice:developer-list'))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DeveloperUpdateView, self).get_context_data(
            **kwargs
        )
        context['form'] = DeveloperForm(
            instance=self.object, prefix='developer'
        )
        bank_account_form = developer_bank_account_formset()
        address_form = developer_address_formset()
        try:
            queryset = DeveloperAddress.objects.filter(id=self.object.address.id)
            address_form = developer_address_formset(queryset=queryset)
            address_form.extra = 0
        except DeveloperAddress.DoesNotExist:
            address_form.queryset = DeveloperAddress.objects.none()
        try:
            queryset = DeveloperBankAccount.objects.filter(
                id=self.object.bank_account.id
            )
            bank_account_form = developer_bank_account_formset(queryset=queryset)
            bank_account_form.extra = 0
        except DeveloperBankAccount.DoesNotExist:
            bank_account_form.queryset = DeveloperBankAccount.objects.none()   

        context['bank_account_form'] = bank_account_form
        context['address_form'] = address_form
        context['action'] = 'update'
        context['error'] = False
        return context
```

My concern is:

I use the following Vue.js code to quickly capture the ZIP code:

And I suspect that the issue lies specifically within the Vue.js part:

```
{% endblock contents %}
{% block javascript %}
    {{ block.super }}

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
            data: {
                street: '',
                district: '',
                city: '',
                state: '',
                country: '',
                isLoading: false,
                isPostalCodeFound: true,
                display_form_address: false,
                display_form_bank: false,
                hasError: '{{ error }}'
            },
            beforeMount: function () {
                this.postal_code = this.$el.querySelector('#id_form-0-postal_code').value
                this.street = this.$el.querySelector('#id_form-0-street').value
                this.district = this.$el.querySelector('#id_form-0-district').value
                this.city = this.$el.querySelector('#id_form-0-city').value
                this.state = this.$el.querySelector('#id_form-0-state').value
                this.country = this.$el.querySelector('#id_form-0-country').value
                this.getError()
            },

            methods: {
                onPostalCodeChange() {
                    if (this.postal_code.length >= 8) {
                        this.fetchPostalCodeData()
                    } else {
                        this.postal_code = ''
                        this.street = ''
                        this.district = ''
                        this.city = ''
                        this.state = ''
                        this.isPostalCodeFound = true
                    }
                },
                showAddress: function () {
                    this.display_form_address = !this.display_form_address;
                },
                showBank: function () {
                    this.display_form_bank = !this.display_form_bank;
                },
                getError: function () {
                    if (this.hasError === "True"){
                        this.showBank();
                        this.showAddress();
                    }
                },
                async fetchPostalCodeData() {
                    try {
                        this.isLoading = true
                        const response = await fetch(
                            `https://viacep.com.br/ws/${this.postal_code}/json/`, {
                                method: 'GET',
                            })
                        const data = await response.json()
                        if (data.erro == true || data.erro == 'true'){
                            this.isPostalCodeFound = false
                        } else {
                            console.log(data)
                            this.street = data.logradouro
                            this.district = data.bairro
                            this.city = data.localidade
                            this.state = data.uf
                        }
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error(error)
                    } finally {
                        this.isLoading = false
                    }
                },

            }
        })
    </script>
```

Could you please provide me with more context or details about this problem? This will help me better understand and assist you in resolving the issue.

I tried using only:

```
        beforeMount: function () {
            this.postal_code = this.$el.querySelector('#id_postal_code').value
            this.street = this.$el.querySelector('#id_street').value
            this.district = this.$el.querySelector('#id_district').value
            this.city = this.$el.querySelector('#id_city').value
            this.state = this.$el.querySelector('#id_state').value
            this.country = this.$el.querySelector('#id_country').value
            this.getError()
        },
```

The post method:

```
<form id="form-container" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form|crispy }}
                    <hr>
                    <div id="form-address" 
                        v-bind:style="this.display_form_address ? 'display:block' : 'display:none'">

                        <div v-if="!isPostalCodeFound" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                          CEP não encontrado
                        </div>
                        <h4 class="card-title">Endereço da incorporadora</h4>
                        {{ address_form.management_form }}
                        {% for address in address_form %}
                            <div class="address-form">
                                {{ address|crispy }}
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
```

Comment: Where do you make a POST request to update the address?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem
I have edited above